# Can we use a map in HttpPost to make our code shorter? (too many fields and we can add more in future)

Tags: apex, rest, map, post, httppost

Can we use a map? And how to do that? Too many fields here already and we can add more in future.

```
@HttpPost
global static Ticket__c postT(String title, String whattime, String whatdate, String whatplace, String externalId, String manager, String phone, String email){

    Ticket__c thisT = new Ticket__c(
        Title__c = title,
        Time__c = whattime,
        Date__c = whatdate,
        Place__c = whatplace,
        Manager__c = manager,
        Email__c = email,
        Phone__c = phone,
        ExtID__c = externalId
        );
    insert thisT;
    return thisT;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create create WrapperClass for Ticket, create JSON object and send it as param of request

```
@HttpPost
global static Ticket__c postT(TicketWrapper wrapper){
    Ticket__c thisT = wrapper.converttoSobject();
    insert thisT;
    return thisT;
}


global class TicketWrapper{
    public String title {get; set;}
    public String whattime {get; set;}
    public String whatdate {get; set;}
    public String whatplace {get; set;}
    public String externalId {get; set;}
    public String manager {get; set;}
    public String phone {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}

    public Ticket__c converttoSobject(){
        return new Ticket__c(
            Title__c = title,
            Time__c = whattime,
            Date__c = whatdate,
            Place__c = whatplace,
            Manager__c = manager,
            Email__c = email,
            Phone__c = phone,
            ExtID__c = externalId
            );
    }
}
```

---

example of such POST body:

```
{
    "wrapper" : {
        "title" : "testservice",
        "whattime" : "testservice",
        "whatdate" : "testservice",
        "whatplace" : "testservice",
        "externalId" : "testservice",
        "manager" : "testservice",
        "phone" : "testservice",
        "email" : "testservice"
    }
}
```